# Azure IMobileServiceSyncTable Parser Stack Overflow

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have an app that uses Azure Mobile offline sync. I'm trying to query a iMobileServiceSyncTable using the following:

```
var listOfIds = dataItems.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();

IEnumerable<DataItemValue> items = await dataItemValueTable
                .Where(i => listOfIds.Contains(i.DataItemId))
                .ToEnumerableAsync();
```

If the number of items in listOfIds is small then everything works fine. If it's larger, e.g. 180, then I get an error:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.SQLiteException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Error executing SQLite command: 'parser stack overflow'.:GetDataItemValues::Sync error: {0}
```

It should be the equivalent of "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Id IN ('a', 'b', 'c'...)", but 180 values in the "IN" statement seems low to be causing an issue? If I use DB Browser for SQLite and manually do they query, it works with no issues.

Any idea why the Azure MobileServices client is throwing the error?

Comment: I actually surprised it is not an OOM (which platform is throwing the parser stack overflow?) How many records are in `dataItemValueTable`?

Comment: It's the UWP platform, and only 486 records in the dataItemValueTable.

Answer (score 1):

> It should be the equivalent of "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Id IN ('a', 'b', 'c'...)", but 180 values in the "IN" statement seems low to be causing an issue?

Following [Debugging the Offline Cache](https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#debugging-the-offline-cache) and override the method `ExecuteQueryInternal`, then you could find that the generated SQL statement looks like this:

> SELECT * FROM [City] WHERE ((((([id] = @p1) OR ([id] = @p2)) OR ([id] = @p3)) OR ([id] = @p4)) OR ([id] = @p5))

I don't know the format or length of your `Id` for querying. You need to test it on your side and obtain a proper count based on your `Id`, then divide your `listOfIds` and execute your query in batch to retrieve your records. The code snippet would look as follows:

```
var listOfIds = dataItems.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
List<DataItemValue> items= new List<DataItemValue>();
int batchSize = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)listOfIds.Count / batchSize); i++)
{
    var ids = listOfIds.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);
    var results = await cityTable.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Id)).ToEnumerableAsync();
    if (results != null)
        items.AddRange(results);
}
```

> Any idea why the Azure MobileServices client is throwing the error?
>
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.SQLiteException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Error executing SQLite command: '**parser stack overflow**'.:GetDataItemValues::Sync error: {0}

The SDK would internally invoke `ExecuteQueryInternal` under [MobileServiceSQLiteStore.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/11c9bcd3c1e16a32cff27460ef836888cbd2d9fa/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore/MobileServiceSQLiteStore.cs), I assumed that the generated SQL statement may hits [Limits In SQLite](https://sqlite.org/limits.html):

> **Maximum Depth Of An Expression Tree**
>
> SQLite parses expressions into a tree for processing. During code generation, SQLite walks this tree recursively. **The depth of expression trees is therefore limited in order to avoid using too much stack space**.
>
> The SQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH parameter determines the maximum expression tree depth. If the value is 0, then no limit is enforced. **The current implementation has a default value of 1000**.